# Prestashop 1.7.4.4 administration 500 error, work only with dev mode on

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

from few days I have this wired problem with Prestashop administration.
When I try to open the page, it's not working.

Then for understand why, I turn on the _PS_MODE_DEV_ and... it's work perfectely!

I upgrade the Prestashop to 1.7.5 but still have the same problem

Now I can not have on _PS_MODE_DEV_ in production or switching when I need to go in administration.

I try to check server and PHP logs, but nothing is reported.

What is happen? how can I solve it?

this are some information:

```
server Info Linux #45-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 19:32:57 UTC 2018 x86_64
Server software: Apache
PHP Version: 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Memory limit: 240M
Max execution time: 360
Max upload files: 128M
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: A 500 error should always log something into the webserver's error log, that's strange. Does the request reach the server at all? Then it should at least be logged in access log... with status code 500? I guess you have alreadytried to empty cache folder (var/cache)?

Comment: not directly by ftp but just in admin panel. Can I delete everything inside cache or just specific folders?

Comment: yes you can delete everything in var/cache

Comment: Thank you for your help, I try now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's work

Comment: Sorry @jww but I have different opinion, I think is on-topic. I still doesn't know why I had that problem. From my point of view can be caused by some prestashop bug or from some module. That was all information I had and I was hope, someone give me some extra idea, and that was. problem solved, thanks to this post! I don't see any other problem now.

Comment: Without having looked at the error log, how do you know that this was in any way related to programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have this kind of problem, the best solution is to remove the cache:

**On Prestashop 1.6**: delete the contents of the cache / smarty / cache and cache / smarty / compile folders

**On Prestashop 1.7**: delete the var / cache folder

Regards,